# Issue with mongodb install on ubuntu ec2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

Update

event `sudo apt update` is not working and showing following message and then connection time out

```
0% [Connecting to us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com ()] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com ()]
```

I have launched an ec2 instance with ubuntu 16 SSD, it can be accessed through openvpn on my system. I am trying to install mongodb on this instance but commands are not working and showing following errors with mentioned commands

I am following this article to install mongodb
https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

command `wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

Above command give me this error

```
Executing: /tmp/tmp.TRAaqd4LFZ/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
--recv
9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
gpg: requesting key E52529D4 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

`sudo apt-get update`  is also not working and shows connection error

I first tried with ubuntu 18.x which but faced same issue so switched to 16.x with a thought that there might be an issue with 18.x

Comment: Can you see the output of `https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc` in your browser? If not, you are most probably having a local network issue since the URL works fine e.g. for me.

Comment: @B--rian Yes it works on my system

Comment: So maybe you can share what is in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and also check whether the URLs in there are reachable? It still looks like a network (or firewall) issue to me.

Comment: Its working fine on other instances with same security group, not sure what is the issue

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a network issue.Use a VPN and try again to check whether it's a network issue.

Comment: Its working fine on other instances with same security group, not sure what is the issue